# Error while deploying firebase app regarding uncaught syntax error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, web-deployment, firebase-hosting

I get this error while deploying my NextJS app on firebase:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

for almost all my js files but I also get this warning

> The script from “https://eco-club-webpage.web.app/_next/static/tORMu0e4SV7nsrZDBvDI-/_buildManifest.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.

I tried solutions suggested on stackoverflow but nothing worked out.

Here is my firebase.json

```json
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ],
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default"
    }
  ],
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "database": {
    "rules": "#"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": ".next",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/server/pages/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true,
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    }
  },
  "remoteconfig": {
    "template": "remoteconfig.template.json"
  }
}
```

My .env.production

```
# Preview URL
NEXT_PUBLIC_URL=https://eco-club-webpage.web.app/
```

My .next/server/index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="icon" href="favico.ico" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest" />
    <meta name="EcoClub:site" content="@ccrsxx" />
    <meta name="EcoClub:card" content="summary_large_image" />
    <title>Eco Club</title>
    <meta name="og:title" content="Eco Club" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="From breaking news and entertainment to sports and politics, get the full story with all the live commentary."
    />
    <meta
      name="og:description"
      content="From breaking news and entertainment to sports and politics, get the full story with all the live commentary."
    />
    <meta property="og:image" content="/home.png" />
    <meta name="og:url" content="https://eco-club-webpage.web.app/" />
    <meta name="next-head-count" content="12" />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="/_next/static/css/a747a3652e5adfc4.css"
      as="style"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="/_next/static/css/a747a3652e5adfc4.css"
      data-n-g=""
    />
    <noscript data-n-css=""></noscript>
    <script
      defer=""
      nomodule=""
      src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-c67a75d1b6f99dc8.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-3433a2a2d0cf6fb6.js"
      defer=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/chunks/framework-9b5d6ec4444c80fa.js"
      defer=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/chunks/main-f0e16f48d3775e5e.js"
      defer=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-f79b9a9b5046cab6.js"
      defer=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/chunks/986-86fabddb1dbcbf61.js"
      defer=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/index-7c905bffd6c4c1c9.js"
      defer=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/tORMu0e4SV7nsrZDBvDI-/_buildManifest.js"
      defer=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/tORMu0e4SV7nsrZDBvDI-/_ssgManifest.js"
      defer=""
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="__next">
      <main class="flex min-h-screen items-center justify-center">
        <i><img src="logo192.png" alt="" /></i>
      </main>
    </div>
    <script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">
      {
        "props": { "pageProps": {} },
        "page": "/",
        "query": {},
        "buildId": "tORMu0e4SV7nsrZDBvDI-",
        "nextExport": true,
        "autoExport": true,
        "isFallback": false,
        "scriptLoader": []
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please ask me any other info you need, I really want to deploy my app. Really disappointed right now, hope someone can help me out. I will be really grateful.